# swing Application is slow when I run it from network on server

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing Application on Java when I run the Jar file after clean and build from my local PC it runs very good and fast but when i move the App folder to the server and make a shurtcut of Jar file to some computers on the network the application runs very slow 
I made my application using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2
the Java runtime is Java 8 update 66

thank you in advanced.

Comment: you should test if those computers ALWAYS slow or become slow after the program have opened by some other stations... any way - it is recommended to use a script that make a copy of the application locally in every machine

Comment: Running any program over the network is going to be slow, but when you consider the fact that the JVM needs to read each class file as it's needed (over the network), this just adds in a larger drain

Comment: Use database in the server and run jars on networked mashines and chage the confi file

Comment: thank you for reply... the computers is not slow but the application is slow very slow when opning any window or search Knowing that the data is not big only about 6 MB!!!

Comment: Add an installer on your program so that it copies all the needed files to the local machines. Then it should work as efficient as it was from your local PC. If you program needs to fetch ***everything*** over the network, of course it will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your application is accessing resources that are slow across the network ie. If you are reading s file it will be quick locally but slower access network. Also if you are reading data from a database and the query results are large and or take long to run, this will also be quicker locally than remote.

I would suggest breaking you application upj into "resources", then turn them all off PR don't use them and bring them back up one by one. That way you can find out what is causing the app to run slow

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your replies 
I tried to copy all the application folders to local machines and change the DB connection to DB file on the server 
but the program still very slow
some one told me that the problem is SQLite and I need to change to SQL Server 2008 or something like it